# How to disable interactive legend of a pie chart in Kendo UI Charts?

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, legend, pie-chart, kendo-chart

I have craete KendoChart pie with legend.
For some reason legend by default is interactive and by clicking on legend items chart enables/disables pieces of the pie.

I didn't find any way to disable this behavior: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/dataviz/chart

[image]

Could it be disabled?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I needed to do the same thing and after some research found out in the Kendo UI documentation the following solution:
- hook to the legendItemClick and legendItemHover events of the chart
- in the handler call e.preventDefault();

Here is the code I used (MVVM-style):

In HTML:

```
data-bind="events: { legendItemClick: disableEvent, legendItemHover: disableEvent } "
```

In the ViewModel:

```
disableEvent: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Here is the article - http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/dataviz/chart

Comment: It would be nicer if this would be an option flag.

Answer (score 6):

Use the code Below

```
legend: {
    position: "bottom",
    visible: false
},
```

Comment: This will hide the legend, not disable the interactivity

Comment: Abiola,  can you try answer to my question? I think you will be able to answer. link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33889722/kendo-chart-legend-label-at-left-color-at-right